# How to return only the earliest date for each user (users have 100s of dates)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, greatest-n-per-group

I've read for hours but am getting nowhere, so was wondering if I could get a little help. Here is my problem, which should be simple for experts (trouble is I am a total noob)

[image]

I would like to only get each unique user and their earliest time recorded, just like this:

[image]

Any thoughts? The simpler the query, the better. Thanks!

Comment: What rdbms are you using(f.e. oracle or MS-SQL-Server)?

Comment: GROUP BY, combined with MIN().

Comment: Hi. All I know is I am using Google Big Query. Does that answer what you need to know?

Comment: Any dbms have this functionality.

Comment: But how do I write or combine the formulas? I know I sound pretty stupid

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use a simple `GROUP BY` with `MIN`:

```
SELECT Username, MIN(Datecolumn) As Datecolumn
FROM dbo.TableName
GROUP BY Username
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks Tim! You rock! Final thing, could someone recommend a good book or any resource to learn SQL? I read for weeks but found pretty basic stuff. Thank you very much everybody!

Comment: @mikewinston: i have mainly learned by doing (and by answering questions on SO) but this seems to be ok: http://www.sqlcourse.com/